# Counting and Probability String Length

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider strings that can be made up from the set $\{a, b, c, d, e, f, \cdots, z, 0, 1, 2, \cdots, 9\}$

1) How many strings of length 8 contain either the letter '$x$' or '$1$'?

2) What is the probability that given a random string of length $8$, the string will contain exactly $1$ '$y$'?

3) How many strings of length $8$ contain at least one '$w$'?

I do not know how to approach problems like this.  I know that for each string position, there are 36 possibilities.  However, how can I use the multiplication rule when a string must contain either one character or another?  Thank you!

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please provide context in terms of what you've tried so far, and how it's worked out.

Answer (score 0):

1)If only two characters "$x$" and "$1$" are allowed, then we can have exactly $2^8$ strings.

2)There are in total $36^8$ strings of length $8$. The number of strings with exactly one "$y$" is $8\cdot 35^7$, that is there are $8$ possible places for the "$y$", and in the rest we can use $35$ characters. Hence, the required probability is $\frac{36^8}{8\cdot 35^7}$.

3)One way to count it is to consider reversely, how many strings have no "$w$". We can get the answer: $36^8-35^8$.

Comment: I think it's possible that problem $1$ is asking for the number of strings that contain either $x$ or $l$, not those that contain *only* $x$ or $l$.  Hard to tell from the given wording.  (To be sure, it would then seem to be a duplicate of problem $3$.)  Your answer for problem $2$ is correct, except that you gave the reciprocal of the probability.

Comment: Assuming problem 1 is asking for the number of strings that contain either x or 1.  There are 35^8 strings that do not contain x.  There are 35^8 strings that do not contain 1.  There are 34^8 that do not contain either.  So there are 36^8 - (2*35^8 - 34^8) that contain either.